# Display background in Div and fill it with clickable items using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am currently looking for a possible solution to draw i.e. 200 clickable items on a background image and save those to a database.

Each item could be draggable and might need to be shift around the background picture, i am thinking about a EDIT Modus.

Note sure this is achievable in a very light way?

Comment: Does each item contain a portion of the background image and thus would need to be moved with the element when dragged? i.e. like a puzzle piece?

Comment: No, the background is just an image or could contain fragments like walls or tables or flowers. Let's think about an office and you wanna move chairs around. Background is a static color, lets say grey and you drop items on it, lets say chairs and tables. You should be able to move those items around and also to click/select those items.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery take a look at [jQuery UI Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

Comment: @hungerstar this looks promising, thanks

Comment: I've done a rough example in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cg2Lb0Lp/2/) (which I'm sure can be improved upon quite a bit). So the one part that is missing is the database save. Which might require each item to have a unique ID and be saved to the database by clicking a _Save_ button that grabs each item's ID, left and top values and submits to the backend. What format you chose to send that data is up to you.

Comment: @hungerstar Cool stuff, let me try this.